# How can I save my result in R into excel files

Tags: r, list

I have  a [list](/questions/tagged/list) result and wants to save it into [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) files for comparisons with other statistical tools. But I keep getting this error. I really do need assistance please. Thanks.

> Error in write_xlsx(nwc_cost, "result_nwc.xlsx") : 
>     Argument x must be a data frame or list of data frames

Comment: What does `nwc_cost` look like? Is it a data.frame? If not, you would need to shape it into on, or be more clear just exactly what you want this Excel file to look like. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `nwc_cost` is a data.frame, you could use the `openxlsx` package with the following code:

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook("workbook")
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "data")
# add your data
writeData(wb, "data", nwc_cost, startCol = 1, startRow = 1)
# then save workbook
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "myexcelfile.xlsx", overwrite = FALSE)
```

You can specify the path in argument file of `saveWorkbook`.
It usually runs very well with all systems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur support

Answer (score 0):

This answer depends on the structure of your data:

```
write_xlsx(as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", nwc_cost)), "result_nwc.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: @Tony Please upvote and accept my answer if it solved your problem.